# Set custom name of artifact with maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Is there a way to change the name of released project? Now my released project name is like this:

```
my-app-1.0.0.war
```

I would like the name be like:

```
my-app##1.0.0.war
```

I'm using maven-release-plugin for releasing my artifacts.

Comment: First why would you like to change that name? apart form that the only thing you can change is the artifactId which is defined in your own project. Furthermore this can't be changed cause otherwise this would break your repository...

Comment: I want it for tomcat, because if you deploy war in tomcat with name: my-app##1.0.0, tomcat knows that the part before hashes is the name of the app and after hashes is the version. If you deploy it with name my-app-1.0.0 tomcat takes whole string as app name, which is unwanted behavior.

Comment: Set correct context in web.xml ...

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<finalName>my-app##1.0.0</finalName>
```

within your project's `<build>` tag in the [`pom.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

> **finalName**: This is the name of the bundled project when it is finally
>   built (sans the file extension, for example: my-project-1.0.jar). It
>   defaults to `${artifactId}-${version}`.

Comment: Yes, I have this already, but it is not working for maven-release-plugin, only for maven-install-plugin.

Comment: finalName will only set the name which is created in the target directory.